# Why do we have the Bakasha, request, of Shema Koleinu, hear our voices in the Shemoneh Esreh?

Tags: tefilla, shemoneh-esrei, shacharis-morning-prayer, mincha-afternoon-prayer

שְׁמַע קולֵנוּ. ה' אֱלהֵינוּ חוּס וְרַחֵם עָלֵינוּ. וְקַבֵּל בְּרַחֲמִים וּבְרָצון אֶת תְּפִלָּתֵנוּ. כִּי אֵל שׁומֵעַ תְּפִלּות וְתַחֲנוּנִים אָתָּה. וּמִלְּפָנֶיךָ מַלְכֵּנוּ. רֵיקָם אַל תְּשִׁיבֵנוּ כִּי אַתָּה שׁומֵעַ תְּפִלַּת עַמְּךָ יִשרָאֵל בְּרַחֲמִים. בָּרוּךְ אַתָּה ה', שׁומֵעַ תְּפִלָּה

Why do we have this seperate Beracha in the Shemoneh Esreh asking Hashem to answer our prayers? What new thing are we asking for that is not included in the previous requests in the Shemoneh Esreh? Isn't it implicit in our previous requests that we want our prayers answered?

Furthermore, if we are on the level for Hashem to respond to our previous prayers then why do I need to request him to answer our prayers and if we are not on the level for Hashem to answer our prayers, then what good is asking for it?

Additionaly:

1)  Why use the term קולנו in the beginning of the paragraph?  Why not listen to our prayers?  Why our voices?

2)  What is the difference between “hearing” and “accepting”?  If he will hear us, doesn’t that mean accept our prayer, if not then why ask for hearing, and if acceptance is what we want, then why ask for hearing?

Comment: @msh210  I added to the question to make it unique.  I still don't feel satisfied with the answers that are given on the question you directed me to.

Comment: If you're unhappy with the answers there, see http://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers. I'll edit this one to remove the duplicate part and reopen it if that's okay with you. Is it?